# Docker :- running Microsoft nano server as a container command not giving any response

Tags: docker

I am running below command in my windows 10 Enterprise machine but the command seems got stuck.

```
docker run -it microsoft/nanoserver cmd
```

I am trying to run a simple windows container for testing.Need some suggestions.

```
docker info

Containers: 3
Running: 0
Paused: 0
Stopped: 3
Images: 1
Server Version: 18.06.1-ce
Storage Driver: windowsfilter
Windows:
Logging Driver: json-file
Plugins:
Volume: local
Network: ics l2bridge l2tunnel nat null overlay transparent
Log: awslogs etwlogs fluentd gelf json-file logentries splunk syslog
Swarm: inactive
Default Isolation: hyperv
Kernel Version: 10.0 14393 (14393.0.amd64fre.rs1_release.160715-1616)
Operating System: Windows 10 Enterprise Version 1607 (OS Build 14393.0)
OSType: windows
Architecture: x86_64
CPUs: 4
Total Memory: 3.999GiB
Name: xxxxxxxxxxx
ID: MTLF:YQV3:B43S:FG35:UFFW:RNXY:INSE:CZAK:T4OK:HGTM:HY5E:WN2M
Docker Root Dir: C:\ProgramData\Docker
Debug Mode (client): false
Debug Mode (server): true
File Descriptors: -1
Goroutines: 43
System Time: 2018-10-09T07:15:45.6413263-04:00
EventsListeners: 2
HTTP Proxy: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
HTTPS Proxy: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
Labels:
Experimental: false
Insecure Registries:
127.0.0.0/8
Live Restore Enabled: false
```

Info command showing below details.Containers are 2 as I have ran above comamnd two times.

Containers: 2
 Running: 0
 Paused: 0
 Stopped: 1
Images: 1

Comment: Can you provide output of `docker info` command?

Comment: I have added full output of docker info in main description.

Comment: It seems it takes time to create container : as in my machine host machine has 8GB ram and though it takes around 25-30 seconds.
And in your case you only have 4GB ram which is minimum requirement for installing Docker on Windows.
https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/install/#what-to-know-before-you-install

Comment: My suggestion is to wait for more time since you are working with minimal hardware resources.

Comment: @fly2matrix But its running more than two days now .Even docker kill command also not responding.Is because of my hardware limitations ?

Comment: You have to remove that hardware limitation. You can try on the same thing on your friend's laptop or desktop to ensure that hardware resources limitation is the only reason. Best of Luck.